# Blocks in objective C /Parse query

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I have a function that fetches list of members using parse query . I have a property of type NSMutableArray which should store the list result named **subscribers**. I have two blocks in code. One block gets the date and once I have date I call another function which further calls a parse cloud method. Here  is the code

```
-(void) fetchMemberList{

PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GroupMembers"];
[query fromLocalDatastore];
[query orderByAscending:@"updatedAt"];
[query whereKey:@"iosUserID" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if(error)
{

}
else{

    if(objects.count==0) {
        _latestTime=[PFUser currentUser].createdAt;
    }

    else {
        PFObject *member=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
        _latestTime =member.createdAt;
    }

    [Data getMemberList:_latestTime successBlock:^(id object) {

        NSMutableDictionary *members = (NSMutableDictionary *) object;

        NSArray *appUser= [members objectForKey:@"app"];
        NSArray *phoneUser=[members objectForKey:@"sms"];
        if(appUser.count>0){
        for(PFObject * appUs in appUser)
        {
            appUs[@"iosUserID"]=[PFUser currentUser].objectId;
            NSString *obj= [appUs objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *child= [appUs objectForKey:@"childern_names"];
            if(child.length>0)
            {
                [_subscriber addObject:child];
            }
            else if(obj.length>0)
            {
                [_subscriber addObject:obj];

            }


            }
            [PFObject pinAllInBackground:appUser];

        }

        if(phoneUser.count>0){
        for(PFObject * phoneUs in phoneUser)
        {
            phoneUs[@"iosUserID"]=[PFUser currentUser].objectId;
            NSString *obj= [phoneUs objectForKey:@"subscriber"];
            NSString *child= [phoneUs objectForKey:@"number"];
            if(child.length>0)
            {
                [_subscriber addObject:child];
            }
            else if(obj.length>0)
            {
                [_subscriber addObject:obj];

            }

        }
            [PFObject pinAllInBackground:phoneUser];

        }


       NSLog(@"%@ subscriber in fetch method",_subscriber);
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    }];


}


}];


}
```

In my **viewdidload** function :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
_subscriber=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


[self fetchMemberList];
NSLog(@"%@ in viewdidLoad",_subscriber);
```

}

So the log in viewdidLoad does not print anything but the one in method gives list of names. I want to store the list in array and put it into tableview. What am I missing here?

Comment: That is the nature of async processes. If you get screwed up by that then try avoiding blocks. Yor code may become longer but eventually is better to understand, especially when your blocks become so large as yours.

Answer (score 0):

The `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` block is asynchronous so `_subscriber isn't immediately available to print after you call your`fetchMemberList` method. That's why the one within the block in fact gives you the list of names -- because by then the callback is complete.